# UPDATE sys_refindex error while upgrading from 8.6.1 to 8.7.1

Tags: typo3

When I try to upgrade a TYPO3 8.6.1 instance to 8.7.1, I get a 'duplicate entry error' while doing the 'Update the hash field of sys_refindex' task in the upgrade wizard. My 'Index Integrity was perfect', all extension were updated before upgrading. I also added https://review.typo3.org/#/c/52399/ to avoid the exception. Any ideas how to avoid this error? Thank you.

Comment: Seems like there is another patch for solving this problem. I'm gonna test it in the afternoon: https://review.typo3.org/#/c/52398/

Comment: The patch works. The update runs through without problems.

Answer (score 0):

After adding this patch, it works: review.typo3.org/#/c/52398